# I am trying to show the download speed(seconds ) and the size in KB for an URL in Java

Tags: java, http, url, connection

I need to read the URL addresses from a file and show the download speed , title tag , and the size in KB.

I am stuck with the size , getContentLengthLong() is negative ,
I am not sure if it`s correct  but I tried :

connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

and I need some help with the download speed .

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class UrlReader {
    static void readTextFromURL( String urlString ) throws IOException {
        System.out.print(urlString + "\t"); // print the url

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        InputStream urlData = connection.getInputStream();

        //print the title
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(urlData);
        String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.print(responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf("<title>") + 7, responseBody.indexOf("</title>")) + "\t");

        //print the size in KB
        long file_size = connection.getContentLengthLong();
        if (file_size < Long.MAX_VALUE){
            System.out.println(file_size/1024 + "KB");
        }
        // print the download speed(seconds)
        urlData.close();
        scanner.close();
    } // end readTextFromURL()  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            FileInputStream ft = new FileInputStream(file);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(ft);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String strline;
            String url;    // The url from the command line or from user input.
            String urlLC; 

            while((strline = br.readLine()) != null){

                url = strline;
                urlLC = url.toLowerCase();
               if ( ! (urlLC.startsWith("http://") || urlLC.startsWith("ftp://") ||urlLC.startsWith("https://")||  
                        urlLC.startsWith("file://"))) {
                    url = "http://" + url;

                }
                try {

                    readTextFromURL(url);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("\n*** Sorry, an error has occurred ***\n");
                    System.out.println(e);                      
                }              
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
} // end main
```

}

Comment: Javadoc of [`getContentLengthLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong--) says: *Returns the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, or **-1 if the content length is not known**.* The server decides whether it wants to send the content length, or not. Nothing you can do about it. Down-voted for lack of research, i.e. reading the **documentation**.

Comment: Given that you've already read the whole file into memory, you can simply check the size of the result (`responseBody.length()`). It won't be an exact match because some characters may be encoded with more than one byte, but in most cases it will be a good approximation.